# Add {% csrf_token %} to multiple templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to upgrade a django project. I need to add the csrf_token tag in multiple templates. Is there anyway i can do this simultaneously without manually editing each template?

Comment: I think that this is a bad idea, you should know your code and it's general behaviour.

Comment: Could you be more detail? csrf token is a requirement in django version 1.2 and above right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can make a new Middleware which will be placed before the `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in settings, then injecting the 
`crsf_token` value to every forms found in request. But yeah, that would be a bad idea to implement.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand why adding csrf_token in template is a bad idea?